# Is it possible to give discounts on in-app subscriptions?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I have a custom subscription plan in my application. So, for the first time user has to pay 100% money. From the second time, user will have some discount. It seems there is a no easy way to implement it.

My approach is:

1. Not to use subscriptions at all and use products instead.
2. create two different SKUs and show the user first SKU for the first time.
3. Make the second SKU consumable and show this to the user from the second time.

Is there a better way to give discounts?

Answer (score 1):

As of now it is not possible to change the price of a subscription.
It is possible to create a new, cheaper subscription plan but changing the price of an existing subscription is not possible.

You could of course charge differently if a user subscribes for a year instead of a month but i'm not sure if that fits your needs.

Another option would be to offer a "downgrade" after a month, which is kinda like your solution but sadly there is not official way of doing it.